# Joomla 2.5 Article Menu Assignment

Tags: joomla2.5

I am trying to assigning a menu with category blog type. The article category is custom created and it is at level 2. Means
 i have a root article category say 'rootcategory'. if i assign menu to this category it is fine.
but i have a child category under 'root category' say child- 1. if i assign this to menu 
it is showing error. like category not found .

Please help me . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you linked "child- 1" with a valid article/ category blog /... which has not the status "registered" or "special"?

Could you provide a URL?